# How to get updates for SLES11 SP3?

Tags: linux, kernel, software-installation, repository, sles

How could I connected to official repository for SLES 11 SP3 to get updates?
I need to update my kernel etc.
[Here my previous active-search post =)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217211/how-to-get-60-day-sles-activation-code), no longer online

Comment: The question is somewhat diffuse: What do you want, want did you try, and what did you get? Usually a valid activation code works for the corresponding version and for future versions (while valid; it's limited in time).

Comment: The link to the previous post is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just get activation code for SLES 12 and use it for SLES 11 SP4(this method doesn't work to SLES 11 SP3).
You will not get an activation code for SP4 in the process of its download - you will see this screen[image]

instead of this:
[image]

Comment: For obvious reasons you won't get a free activation code for every service pack of the same release; maybe that was your original problem. Today you would use openSUSE Leap 15.3 instead of SLES15 SP3 when you don't need professional support.